# PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded but no PHP source for my version?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to install Magento but getting the error above.  I've scoured the web for how to create the mcrypt extension (http://www.oldapps.com/php_programming_language.php?old_php=12364), but without luck because I can't find my version of PHP to install it (php 5.3.26).

I added mcrypt to the extensions list but now I just get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2013 19:05:08)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

Scour the web for the source, try here: http://www.oldapps.com/php_programming_language.php?old_php=12364